# Problems running app in iOS 7 with CocoaPods in XCode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, cocoapods

I have an app in `iOS 7` and `iOS 8`. Now, I have adapted the app for `watchOS 2` and `iOS 9`. I can't run the app in `iOS 7` because I get some problems with `pods` in some clases. I have this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kPOPViewBounds", referenced from:
      -[HomeFiltersCollectionViewManager animateAlphaToView:withDelay:bounds:] in HomeFiltersCollectionViewManager.o
  "_AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding", referenced from:
      -[MNBBaseNetworkService requestWithMethod:path:parameters:] in MNBBaseNetworkService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFImageCache", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_AFImageCache_$_AlternativeImageCacheForAFNetworking in AFImageCache+AlternativeImageCacheForAFNetworking.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImageDownloader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MNPoiListDownloader.o
      objc-class-ref in UIImageView+Blurred.o
      objc-class-ref in MNBNotificablePoiList.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImageManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CampaingProvider.o
      objc-class-ref in UIImageView+Blurred.o
      objc-class-ref in IPadHomeViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in IPadDestinationLandingCollectionViewManager.o
```

and many more...

I also have these warnings: (for example)

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-AFNetworking.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..b/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-AFNetworking.a
ld: warning: ignoring file `/Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-ARAnalytics.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-ARAnalytics.a`
```

any a lot of more..

Anyone knows why I have this problems? I have tried with a test app and Everything works fine with `WatchOS` and `Pods` and `iOS 7`

Comment: Did you try to pod install again your podfile ?

Comment: Yes.. but it doesn't work either

Comment: Ok, try to deep clean Xcode (apple+alt+maj+K)

Comment: No.. I did a lot of cleans and pod installs and nothing